# XML Schema doesn't work

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to link an XML Schema with an XML file. I followed this example: [XSD How To](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_howto.asp).

The `note.xml` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<note
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3schools.com note.xsd">
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

And the `note.xsd` looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
targetNamespace="http://www.w3schools.com"
xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="note">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="to" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="from" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="body" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

But when I open the `note.xml`, it just looks like a regular XML in my browser, with the description: `This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.`
These files are both in the same directory.

Comment: are you confusing attaching an XML Schema with attaching an XSLT transformation? because your browser is telling you about the absence of a stylesheet, not the absence of a schema

Comment: You are right! Can you please put your comment to the answers, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you confusing attaching an XML Schema with attaching an XSLT transformation? because your browser is telling you about the absence of a stylesheet, not the absence of a schema

Answer (score 0):

a XSD(schema) only serves the validation purpose for any xml...whereas a XSLT is used to serve the styling purpose for a XML -wch is simply absent in ur xml so how could you expect any styling in your browser when you are running this XML file...!!!